# How to build last tag with concourse ci?

Tags: continuous-integration, concourse

Is it possible to build on the last tag with concourse? Similar to */tags/* in the branch specifier with jenkins.

Answer (score 2):

There is a tag_filter property available for the git resource type. See [git resource type documentation](https://github.com/concourse/git-resource) for further documentation.

So something like:

```
resources:
- name: source-code
  type: git
  source:
    uri: git@github.com:concourse/git-resource.git
    branch: master
    tag_filter: "*"
```

should work.